# What does CLD do here?

Tags: delphi, assembly

I have seen code

```
procedure FillDWord(var Dest; Count, What: dword); assembler ;
asm
  PUSH EDI
    MOV EDI, Dest
    MOV EAX, What
    MOV ECX, Count
    CLD
    REP STOSD
  POP EDI
end;
```

I googled CLD and it says it clears the direction flag... so is it important here? after I removed it, the function seems working fine.

Comment: `CLD` may be omitted as direction flag must be cleared due to Delphi rules for assembler code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The direction flag controls if - during the execution of `REP STOSD` the `EDI` register will be incremented or decremented.

In case of a cleared direction flag (e.g. after execution of `CLD`) the pointer will be incremented, so the function does a memory fill.

The `CLD` is in this code because the programmer probably was not able to guarantee that the direction flag was cleared. Therefore he made sure that it is cleared before executing `REP STOSD`.

If the code works when `CLD` is removed, then the direction flag was clear at the entry of the function. Since the direction flag is not part of the calling conventions that was just by luck. It could be the other way next time, and in this case your program will very likely crash.

Clearing/setting the flag is a very fast operation, so it's good practice to add them to the assembler code. This also makes it easy for other programmers to understand your function because the state of the direction flag is explicitly defined.

Comment: Suggestion for alternate wording: "incremented or not" sounds a bit like the register could remain unchanged. It would be clearer if it said "incremented or decremented".

Comment: @Michael thanks for your lectorat work on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `stosd` command can either work down the memory, incrementing EDI, or up the memory, decrementing it. This depends on the value of the direction ("D") flag. If the flag is set to 1 upon function entrance and never explicitly cleared, it'll misbehave wildly. There's no convention on the default value of that flag; so the function plays it safe.

EDIT: Egor says Delphi has a convention :) Still, better safe than sorry.